# Mail crashed, now insists it's the first run, wants to import emails

Tags: mail.app, email, crash

**EDIT:
I couldn't find any other solution to this, so I went ahead and let it import.  Seems OK, except of course that I know have a pile of "Recovered Messages" mailboxes with thousands of emails in them.  Mildly annoying but seemingly not the end of the world.  I did find some messages in Drafts that just say "This message was not found in the specified location because it was moved or deleted. Please resync your client." now, which is somewhat concerning but not much I can do about it I guess.**

MacOS Catalina, 2018 MacbookPro.

My mail.app crashed randomly, so I relaunched and now every time, it insists it's the first time it's been run and wants to import emails.  As of yet I have not allowed it to do so.

My internet searching has turned up basic stuff which all boiled down to deleting mail related stuff from ~/Library and restoring from a backup.  I did this, restoring from a Time Machine backup as of yesterday (actually I tried half a dozen times from an hour ago, to yesterday).  No change at all, I can't run Mail without having to import my emails.

I really don't like the idea of doing this import as I don't trust it, and there's no reason it should be required in the first place.  Anyone know what's going on here or have a fix?

[image]

Comment: "Deleting mail related stuff from ~/Library" is a bit vague, but assuming you did do that, you have no mail whatsoever.  Depending on your mail server config, you likely now *must* import things.  That said, what's it asking to import?  Can you provide a screen shot?  What type of server are you connecting to, IMAP, POP, Exchange?

Comment: I deleted *and restored from TimeMachine* though.  Everything I could find in ~/Library that related to mail.  I actually moved it to the desktop, not trash, but the bottom line is I removed it and replaced with a backup.  I'm using IMAP, in theory I could just let the import do its thing and would probably be OK, but past experience has me not generally trusting mysterious things like this that shouldn't be happening, but are.  Screenshot added to OP.

Comment: That message is telling you the Mail app itself was updated and it needs to import the settings, rules, everything from the old Mail database to the new one.

Comment: But the app was not updated.  It simply crashed, and was immediately relaunched.  No update took place.  Also note it is not mentioning settings, but the messages themselves.  This is what concerns me.